# How many 行书 semi-cursive handwriting variants

Tags: handwriting

In common mandarin chinese, How i wanted to know how many "known" 行书 semi-cursive handwriting variants are they?

I also wanted to ask two questions (the answer could be different although these two questions "seems" to appear the same) :

1) Which of those "known" 行书 semi-cursive handwriting variants are most popular in use nowadays by common Chinese people?

2) Which of those "known" 行书 semi-cursive handwriting variants has the most comprehensive & complete guide (in terms of number of characters which they construct on how to write the charaters in that variant) ?

Regards

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule about it. One usually copies from those he likes most, or develops his own way with reference to others.

Comment: This is like asking "how many cursive styles of handwriting exist in English (alphabet languages)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn 行书 for practical, I can post some styles for you.

**荆霄鹏**

[image]

====

**田英章**

[image]

========

**顾仲安**

[image]

======

**卢中南**

[image]

========

**任平**

[image]

They are the most famous calligraphers modern times, the most populars are 顾仲安 and 田英章, my favourite is 顾仲安.

Here is more from 顾仲安.

楷书
[image]

行书
[image]

顾仲安 publish many 字帖, and there are video tutorials, groups on line.

Comment: Thanks. From where did you get this list from? and can you post a link to those video tutorials? Is there any in english the tutorials?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 I collected from the web, I think you can join 百度贴吧 顾仲安吧, it is like reddit to get more help, and all the resource you will need. https://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=顾仲安

Comment: Does it accepts English language questions about Chinese language / handwriting ? The forum in the link I mean.